# Problems after installing bootcamp drivers

Tags: windows, mac, drivers, boot-camp

I  set up a windows 10 Partition with bootcamp and after installing the bootcamp drivers, windows doesn't start normally. It opens the window where you can choose between 4 options.

1.continue
2.use a device
3. Troubleshoot
4. Turn off your pc

When i click on continue it restarts 2 or 3 times and then it opens the window again.
Everytime i install this bootcamp drivers my screen does weird things ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, fixed it LMAO.
I told Apple Care too about this problem.
The USB c driver aren't working correctly when having a second monitor connected while startup.
I just unplugged my Monitor and it worked.